# How do I move a local Laravel project to an AWS server?

Tags: php, laravel, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I have a localhost Laravel project running on Windows 10 with XAMPP, and everything's working fine. I now want to move this project to AWS so that I can share it with other people.

Specifically, I want to put it on an EC2 server with Apache and PHP 7.0+, and then put the MariaDB instance on an RDS instance that I'll connect to.

I know how to set up an EC2 instance and an RDS instance. I also know how to set up the MariaDB instance an edit the `.env` file to point to the RDS MariaDB instance.

What I don't know how to do though is move / set up the Laravel project on the EC2 instance so that all of my files are there and when I go to the IP address of the EC2 instance, it loads the root controller (i.e., `Route::get('/', function () { ... })`).

My thought process was to move everything over so that the `public` folder of my Laravel project matched up with the `/var/www/html/` directory on the server, but maybe that's not right.

Also, should I copy all the npm/composer files over from my local project to the server (via FTP, etc.), or should I skip those and then run an `npm install` and `composer install` (sorry, don't recall the exact command) once all the other files are on the server?

Do I need to edit the Apache config to get things working? How? What kind of file permissions need to possibly be set?

These are the main questions I have, but I may be missing other stuff as well. Thank you.

Comment: perhaps you have small knowledge about setup PHP project with Apache, for simple try just copy your whole Laravel project source from local to server, and find way to change your server Apache's configure from /var/www/html/ to your <laravel_project_dir>/public/

Comment: Makes sense. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to set the document root equal to the public folder of your project. So normally the site will be at `/var/www/yoursite/` and the document root in your apache config will be `/var/www/yoursite/public`. That way the route `'/'` will be your public folder.
 The `/var/www/html` folder will be the default document root of apache which must be left alone.
In the folder `/var/www/yoursite` you can pull your changes from github and then run `composer install` and `npm install`.